# Wayland option in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wayland

Why "Wayland" option in Ubuntu 18.04 makes my Laptop more hot? 
Need to provide direct Feedback option inside Ubuntu OS to make Users life simple in reporting problems or improvements.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04, the wayland login option will automatically switch off the Nvidia proprietary drivers and use the integrated graphics (e.g. i915).  For heavy graphics loads, the Nvidia drivers would be more efficient (lower temperatures).  Generally, which driver is most efficient depends upon the type of graphics being displayed.